# Deploying a webpart in additional page head delegate control

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am deploying a simple webpart in AdditionalPageHead delegate control but the changes do not show up below is my element.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="Hider" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="Hider\Hider.webpart" Url="Hider.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
    <Control ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
             ControlClass="AnonymousAccessHandler.AnonymousAccessHandler.Hider"
             Id="AdditionalPageHead"
             Sequence="10"></Control>
</Elements>
```

Comment: I solved my problem, the control class name was not correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

1. Is your elements file included as part of a feature definition?
2. Is that feature activated at the location where you want to render the control?

I should also point out that the AdditionalPageHead control is used to add content within the `<head></head>` html tags, and therefore is not going to visibly show up anywhere on the rendered page. You'll have to check the page source in the browser to see if the output is generated.

With that in mind, using a web part for this task seems a little heavy handed; all you need is a simple ServerControl or UserControl.